# Run aritmethic function on mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to perform arithmetic functions on a table in mysql database. on the table there are 5 field where the first field is the primary key and other fields is an integer data type.

Assume a field that has a data type is integer W, X, Y, and, Z. I want to do the calculation by the following formula:

> (Xi - Xavg)^2

Xi = value of record i

Xavg = average value of field X

I write my query like this:

```
SELECT W, X, Y, Z, POW(W - AVG(W),2), POW(X - AVG(X),2), POW(Y - AVG(Y),2), POW(Z - AVG(Z),2)
FROM nilai
```

And here the result:
[image]

But the result only showing the first record. is there any way, so i can display all the records and the results of the calculations?

Comment: It will show all the records in the table as there is no where clause. How many records are in the table?

Comment: `select count(*) from nilai` to find out how many records are in the table.

Comment: there are 36 records in that table

Comment: add  `limit 1000`  to the select i.e.  `select ... from nilai limit 1000;`.

Comment: doesn't work. still only show the first record

Comment: does `select * from nilai` show all the rows? If not then there is something odd with the tool you are using to run the query. What are you using to run the query?

Comment: yeah, `select * from nilai` show all the rows. nothing is wrong with my tool